# React toggle button (class component) not toggling

Tags: reactjs, class

I am trying to make toggle button using class component react, but its not toggling at all.
Here is my code part

```
class ModalAdd extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: true,
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button outline color="success" size="sm" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Add Item
        </Button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.active} toggle={this.toggle}>
      </div>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `this.active` instead of `this.state.active`

And you don't need the `this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);` in the constructor as you're already defined the `toggle` as an arrow function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its help me alot